# AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release

Tags: javascript, react-native

I don't know why I'm getting this warning message. I using @react-native-async-storage/async-storage.

Is there a way to fix it, without ignoring with YellowBox.

The warning message goes away when I remove the firebase config code

Warning Message:
AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Package.json

```
dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "firebase": "^9.4.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: There will be no updates in future for async-storage. You should use alternate for this.

Comment: How are you importing `AsyncStorage` in your file?

Comment: `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'`

Comment: What are some alternative to this library